# c# BackgroundWorker and Treeview in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

**Env**: C#, VStudio 2013, 4.5 Framework, Winforms

**Goal** : Insert, inside a Treeview, the content of a folder (Sub folder + files) so that user can select those needed. Display a progressbar that show the progress of loading the files and folders in the TreeView.

**What i've done so far** : Everything in my goal but ...

**Error**: "*This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently*". I get this error sometimes when I go use other apps while my application is running.

**My code** :

```
     void backgroundWorkerTreeView_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
                {
                    var progress = (((float)(int)e.Argument / (float)totalFilesInTN) * 100);
                    var value = (int)Math.Round((float)progress);
                    backgroundWorkerTreeView.ReportProgress(value, e.Argument.ToString());
                }
void backgroundWorkerTreeView_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    stStripBarMain.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    toolStripStatusLabelPrct.Text = " Loading " + e.UserState + " of " + totalFilesInTN;
                }
void backgroundWorkerTreeView_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    //do the code when bgv completes its work
                }

        private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
                        if (path != "")
                        {
                            var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                            treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo, 0));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + "[" + DateTime.Now + "] " + e.Message + "\r\n";
                    }
                }

    private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, int indice)
            {

                    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
                    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        if ((directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
                        {
                            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory, indice));
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                    {
                        if ((IsNullOrEmpty(ext)) ||
                            (Array.IndexOf(ext, Path.GetExtension(file.Name.ToLowerInvariant())) >= 0))
                        {
                            if ((GetTriggerEvent(file.FullName).Contains(txtParamEvent.Text)) || (txtParamEvent.Text == ""))
                            {
                                indice++;
                                backgroundWorkerTreeView.RunWorkerAsync(indice);
                                TreeNode newTN = new TreeNode();
                                newTN.Text = file.Name + @"   (" + GetTriggerEvent(file.FullName) + @")";
                                newTN.Name = file.FullName;
                                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(newTN);
                                newTN.Tag = "msg";
                            }
                        }
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }
                    return directoryNode;
            }
```

Thanks for the help

Richard

Comment: A background worker cannot be told to run multiple times. You are calling `backgroundWorkerTreeView.RunWorkerAsync(indice);` in a loop.

Comment: You didn't provide any way to stop the worker.  And apparently no code either that checks that the worker is busy so can't be started again by accident.  You'd also better check what happens when your close the window while the worker is still busy.  And get rid of that gawdawful DoEvents() call.   It is ... not done.